# Self update a python script posted on github

Tags: python, git, github

I have made a bot that tracks the earning of a mining rig, but the script is running in a friend of mine house, therefore whenever I update it I have to send the new version to my friend. I have thought to load the program to github, inside the script periodically check if the repo that contains it has been modified, and if so, to update itself.

I have tried to pull the whole repo, launch it and destroy the hold files, but I dont think it's a good idea (if I have to deal with big files for examples).

I also have found a pypi function called selfupdate (https://pypi.org/project/selfupdate/) but there is not much documentation and I didn't get how to make it work

How can I manage to make the script update himself pulling the newer version from github?

Comment: and what's your question? :)

Comment: How can I do that? How can I make the script update himself